# how can I be redirected to the admin panel to travel and not to the main page of the site?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a project that we were asked to do for an internship. we have to set up an e-commerce website. for this, we chose Voyager 1.4 for the administration of the site.
I used

```
php artisan voyage:install
```

and I created an administrator with

```
php artisan voyager: admin your@email.com --create
```

Everything was fine for me until I logged out now when I log back in I am directly redirected to the user side of my site and not to my Voyager 1.4 administration panel.

My concern is how can I solve this problem in such a way that I can log into my admin panel and that user who wants to buy at the site level is also often redirected to his user page.

Comment: On login you want to redirect user to `travel` route?

Comment: Yes But taking into account when the administrator connects he is directed to his backoffice and the simple user who is there to buy a product connects to his user space.

Answer (score -1):

when you enter your credentials, then execute php code (example):

```
if(isset($_POST['loginbutton'])){
  $admin_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['admin_email']);
  $admin_pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['admin_pass']);
  $get_admin = "select * from admin_database where admin_email='$admin_email' AND 
  admin_pass='$admin_pass'";

  $run_admin = mysqli_query($con,$get_admin);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($run_admin);

  if($count==1){

    $_SESSION['admin_email']=$admin_email;

    echo "<script>alert('Logged in. Welcome Back')</script>";

    echo "<script>window.open('page.php?redirected_page','_self')</script>";

  }else{
    echo "<script>alert('Email or Password is Wrong!')</script>";
  }


}
```

Comment: the problem here is that I don't code php simply I use the php laravel framework its version 7